# How to add durations of partial records

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server table as follows (`calltable`). This is actually a CDR (Call Detail Records) table. Our current system breaks CDRs in every 30 minutes (1800 seconds). So I need to get the actual call duration of a particular call using a SQL Server query (`resulttable`).

Please note that there can be other call records with same calling number (`anumber`) & called number (`bnumber`) less than 1800 seconds. Those records should be there without any summation.

Calltable:

[image: calltable]

Resulttable:

[image: resulttable]

Comment: This data structure provides no mechanism for determining whether two adjacent CDRs represent the same or different calls.  In your example data it is surely possible that the second row was a call that lasted 1800 seconds and the third row is NOT a continuation of that call but a 200 second call that occurred later in the same 30 minute period.  Do you need to distinguish those two situations?

Comment: Partial CDRs are not in a sequence in the actual database table. They can be anywhere in the table. Only way to identify this partial CDRs are same anumber,bnumber & added 30 minutes to calldate.

Comment: CDRs usually include a Call ID that can link multiple parts of a call toghether.

Comment: This functionality is not there in our current system. So we are moving to another Interconnect billing system. Before that, I have to reconcile some operator CDRs with our current system CDRs due to a discrepancy.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just calculate the end date from the duration, then use gaps & islands algorithms to determine what is the same call (assuming small gaps in the time are still considered one call), and if you need, then again calculate it back to duration

Comment: If the call duration is 1800 seconds in a CDR, then it needs to find any CDR in the table with same anumber, bnumber and 30 minutes added calldate. So any idea to create a query for this?

Comment: @DilshanPeiris Yes, and that's what my instruction was for. Is there something unclear?

Comment: Actually I do not have any idea about gaps & islands algorithms. :-(

Comment: @DilshanPeiris And you don't even try to do anything yourself? https://www.google.com/#q=gaps+islands+sql+server

Comment: @DilshanPeiris `While`, `if` and `else` are control-of-flow functions. I don't see how those are related to this problem in any way.